# How to Change Torque Map Slider Text

Tags: carto, timeslider

I am new to CartoDB and NOT a programmer. I am trying to make a simple torque map that changes by year and I do not want the slider text to include or display the month, just the year.

Is this possible to do with little to no programming?.

Answer (score 1):

You need some programming to do that:

```
 cartodb.createVis('map', 'http://andrew.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/b5cece38-4af4-11e3-bfb4-3085a9a9563c/viz.json')
        .done(function(vis, layers) {
          var slider = vis.getOverlay('time_slider')
          slider.formatter(function(d) {
            return "month:" + d.getUTCMonth();
          })
        })
```

The complete example: http://bl.ocks.org/javisantana/9066265