# HTML CartoDB timeSlider Animation Map

Tags: carto, html, timeslider

I have created a web map using CARTODB API. I'm wanting to make an animation map with my points. The map points displays properly, but the time slider will not display as well as no animation of points.
Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Easy example | CartoDB.js</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cartodb.com/assets/favicon.ico" />
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>

    <script>

function main() {
        cartodb.createVis('map', 'http://mmckeever92.carto.com/api/v2/viz/042d1afc-7df7-40a7-8765-bebcd4b0e855/viz.json', {
            shareable: true,
            title: true,
            description: true,
            search: true,
            tiles_loader: true,
            center_lat: 43.728,
            center_lon: -79.379,
            zoom: 11
        })
        .done(function(vis, layers) {
      var slider = vis.getOverlay('time_slider')
      slider.formatter(function(d) {
        return  d.getUTCMonth()+"-"+ d.getUTCDay() + " "+ d.getUTCHours() + ":"+ d.getUTCMinutes();
      })
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

      window.onload = main;
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a feeling that I am having the same issue as they did here:
[Torque map slider formatting problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210406/torque-map-slider-formatting-problem)

Does anyone have a clue as to why my time slider won't display in my map?

Answer (score 1):

BUILDER vizjsons are not fully compatible with CARTO.js or Torque.js, you will need to use `createLayer` as [in this working example](http://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/fb8407b3403ea2fc82b4).